# Creating a vector of set

Tags: c++, vector, set

In my code I have a vector defined:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<shared_ptr<foo> > > > > fooBoxes;
```

I am initializing the vector using:

```
int BOX_NUM = 12 //this is actually defined elsewhere

fooBoxes.resize(BOX_NUM);
for (int i = 0; i<BOX_NUM; i++){
  fooBoxes[i].resize(BOX_NUM);
  for (int j = 0; j < BOX_NUM; j++){
    fooBoxes[i][j].resize(BOX_NUM);
    for (int k = 0; k < BOX_NUM; k++){
      fooBoxes[i][j][k].resize(0);
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that the use of vector is causing me a segmentation fault and I want to replace `fooBoxes` to be:

```
vector<vector<vector<set<shared_ptr<foo> > > > > fooBoxes
```

what do I do in the `for` loops? simply remove the `resize(0)` part?

**Edit:**
This is the output of valgrind in the crash:

```
==2258== Invalid read of size 8
==2258==    at 0x439237: trans(int) (stl_iterator.h:704)
==2258==    by 0x413B0E: membrane::MCstep(int) (membrane.cpp:490)
==2258==    by 0x402767: main (main.cpp:14)
==2258==  Address 0x7932420 is 8 bytes after a block of size 24 free'd
==2258==    at 0x4A05743: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:346)
==2258==    by 0x405636: vec::~vec() (valarray_array.h:71)
==2258==    by 0x437D66: trans(int) (transFile.cpp:64)
==2258==    by 0x413B0E: membrane::MCstep(int) (membrane.cpp:490)
==2258==    by 0x402767: main (main.cpp:14)
==2258==
==2258== Invalid read of size 8
==2258==    at 0x439240: trans(int) (stl_vector.h:604)
==2258==    by 0x413B0E: membrane::MCstep(int) (membrane.cpp:490)
==2258==    by 0x402767: main (main.cpp:14)
==2258==  Address 0x111 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2258==
==2258==
==2258== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2258==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x111
==2258==    at 0x439240: trans(int) (stl_vector.h:604)
==2258==    by 0x413B0E: membrane::MCstep(int) (membrane.cpp:490)
==2258==    by 0x402767: main (main.cpp:14)
==2258==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2258==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2258==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2258==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2258==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
```

I believe that the problem is that I'm not careful enough when I try to delete/put a bead into a vector and this is why I want to move to set.

Comment: The segmentation fault is certainly not caused by `vector` but by a bug or in your code.

Comment: I just tried to compile and change stuff. I don't suspect that those line are the source of the bug. The program crushes when I try to ``push_back`` a ``foo`` into a vector

Comment: I thought your contained type was a pointer type, how can you push back an object? Post some actual code, maybe we can help.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I'm pushing back a shared pointer to the vector. I know that the program is legal since it's only crash after a long run. I don't want to post the code since I believe this is more complicated than a wrong notation in a single file but rather something wrong with my paradigm. I will post in a moment the result of valgrind though

Comment: @Yotam: It's hard to debug a paradigm. All the code you've posted so far has been correct. One suggestion, instead of using `fooBoxes[i]` to access your vectors use `fooBoxes.at(i)`. They work exactly the same except that `at` will throw an exception if you try to access an out of bounds element in your vector. Given your heavy vector use that seems a likely cause of your problem. Put a catch for exception in your main function.

Comment: @Yotam, it is generally not a good idea nesting STL types (here you got 4 levels of vector), each STL container has a non-negligible overhead, maybe it would be possible to pack everything in a multidim array (or in a class that stores the data in a single vector and internally transforms indices into a single linear index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you want to achieve. Your code will most definitely compile if you remove `fooBoxes[i][j][k].resize(0);` since the `std::set` does not support this function.

Comment: Will I be able to insert and erase elemnts into the set straight away?

Comment: Yes, this should not be a problem. You can do that with `fooBoxes[i][j][k].insert(value)` and `fooBoxes[i][j][k].erase(value)`.

Comment: Just a note, `set` has completely different semantics from `vector`

Comment: @Andreas Brinck: Do you mean functions? I know, I'm going through the code and changing this...

Comment: The most important difference is that the elements in a `set` are always sorted.